# Is 民主党派 NGO in China?

Tags: culture

I happened to see a road sign, on which it is marked 广西区各民主党派机关 and I kept wondering why the political parties which are eight or nine in numbers have to put their regional headquarters together?

It is unbelivable if you would see the same in the US or other western countries. Is it likely that the Republican and the Democratic work in the same compound or even in the same building or on the same floor?!

Another question is that are they NGOs? Do they make registration with the administrative authorities to become legal entities? It looks like we cannot find their information through the usual apps or tools like 天眼查 or 企查查.

Here in my opinion, it is not a question of politics, but a question of culture, which could throw some light on Chinese language learning. So I sincerely request the admin, please do not delete this.

Answer (score 4):

> Is 民主党派 NGO in . . .

## no

there’re two wiki pages in chinese about this topic, read between the lines

[中國八大民主黨派](https://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B%E5%85%AB%E5%A4%A7%E6%B0%91%E4%B8%BB%E9%BB%A8%E6%B4%BE)

[民主黨派](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E6%B0%91%E4%B8%BB%E5%85%9A%E6%B4%BE)

the notions of “country / nation”, “government” & “political party” are distinguish in western cultures. well, in “you-know-where”, the party is . . .

> why the political parties which are eight or nine in numbers have to put their regional headquarters together?

first, these parties are components of the political system, presumed approved by the communist (民主黨派係中共同意組成為前提)

these parties are shepherded by the communist (中國共產黨領導的多黨合作制); that these parties are not striving for power, significantly different from western political party.

theses parties have guaranteed seats in the national people’s congress (全國人民代表大會); that ngo in western societies do not have this “privelege”

have fun, and be safe

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, Chinese politics works different from Western politics...

As for NGO, sure, there are loads of them. There are humanitarian ones such as Oxfam, environmental ones, and even civilian rescue groups that work disaster relief.